# xml data into nodeset, and two lists into table

Tags: r, xml, list, nodes

I extracted XML data using `xmlParse`. I then used `getNodeSet` to extract a node set that looks like this:

```
<field dollars="false" unit="(deaths/1,000 live births)" rankorder="1" name="Infant mortality rate" id="f2091">
  <rank number="175.90" dateEstimated="true" dateLatest="2011-12-31" dateEarliest="2011-01-01" dateText="2011 est." country="ao"/>
  <rank number="149.20" dateEstimated="true" dateLatest="2011-12-31" dateEarliest="2011-01-01" dateText="2011 est." country="af"/>
  <rank number="112.22" dateEstimated="true" dateLatest="2011-12-31" dateEarliest="2011-01-01" dateText="2011 est." country="ng"/>
  <rank number="111.35" dateEstimated="true" dateLatest="2011-12-31" dateEarliest="2011-01-01" dateText="2011 est." country="ml"/>
  <rank number="105.56" dateEstimated="true" dateLatest="2011-12-31" 
</field>
```

Next I used `xmlSApply` with the `xmlGetAttr` command (`xmlSApply(nodeset1, xmlGetAttr, "number")`) to pull out part of the node into a list.

> $rank [1] "175.90"
>
> $rank [1] "149.20"
>
> $rank [1] "112.22"
>
> $rank [1] "111.35"

I did it again with a different word (`xmlSApply(nodeset1, xmlGetAttr, "country")`) to get another list:

> $rank [1] "ao"
>
> $rank [1] "af"
>
> $rank [1] "ng"
>
> $rank [1] "ml"

Now I want to make a table merging the values in each list. I cannot seem to do this. I think the problem is that each item list begins with `$rank`, but I do not know how to get rid of it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

if your nodeset has a table like structure your best bet is to convert it to data.frame using function xmlToDataFrame from the XML package.

df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=ns)